# AttributeError in CreateView - Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am developing a program that consists of sales.

I want that when registering a sale, the reduction of the stock of the sold product is deducted. When doing so, the quantity of the product is discounted but the sale is not created and I get this error:
The error now is: `AttributeError at /ventas/create/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

and in the console:  `url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

forms.py:

```
class VentasForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Formulario modelo de ventas."""


    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Venta
        fields = ('fecha', 'cliente', 'producto', 'cantidad', 'forma_pago')

    def clean(self):
        """Verificar si hay stock del producto."""
        data = super().clean()

        producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)
        if producto.cantidad <= float(self.data['cantidad']):
            raise forms.ValidationError('No hay suficiente stock del producto.')
        return data

    def save(self):
        """Restar stock."""
        data = self.cleaned_data

        producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)

        producto.cantidad -= float(data['cantidad'])
        producto.save()
```

views.py:

```
class CreateVentasView(CreateView):
    """Registrar venta."""

    template_name = 'ventas/create.html'
    form_class = VentasForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ventas:list')
    context_object_name = 'venta'
```

and in the template: {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: You should not raise the exception in the `save` method, but in the `clean` method. The clean method is for checking the data, the save method is used to make the changes persistent.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there i update the post with what i did and the error i get now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ModelForm` `save()` method is throwing away the return value of the superclass save.  You need to return it, eg.

```
def save(self):
        """Restar stock."""
        data = self.cleaned_data

        producto = Product.objects.get(id=data['producto'].pk)
        producto.cantidad -= float(data['cantidad'])
        producto.save()

        return super().save()
```

As a general rule: If you know for SURE that a method you are overriding never returns anything, then you don't have to worry about returning anything.  But if there's any chance that a method you are overriding could return something useful (now or in the future), then play it safe and return whatever they return.  It'll save you a lot of headaches later on.

One thing to think about here, is that you have a small race condition, where if two people order within a few milliseconds of each other, it is possible that you could end up thinking that you have enough stock because customer #1 checked the stock.. it was ok.. then customer #2 checks the stock before customer #1's order was saved.  This would cause both orders to be saved when there may be only enough stock for the first order.

Comment: it doesn't work, the same error keeps getting

Comment: Ahh fixed, you were also not saving your sale only decrementing the product quantity.